# Modify output of custom loop using WP_query

Tags: wp-query

I have a custom loop from a custom post type and I want to NOT display posts with the category 'slider'.

I'm using this to set up the query:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'hotwives', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

I was going to use this in the $args variable:

```
'category' => 'slider'
```

But not sure how to make that NOT display the posts from category 'slider'.

And, incidentally, when I use that in the $args variable it still shows every post, not just the 'slider' posts.  So, seems I'm not on the right track regardless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'hotwives',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'slider',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Use that as the args for your `WP_Query` and you should get posts that aren't in the category taxonomy. It also has the advantage of being expansible to more than one exclude, etc. If you're using a custom taxonomy, change `'taxonomy'`'s value to the name of that taxonomy.

Docs: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Good stuff.  Works perfectly.   Thanks for the detailed answer.